# VS 2013 / BizTalk 2010 - Generated Schemas not adding to correct sub-directory

Tags: visual-studio-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm adding generated schemas to my VS 2013 BizTalk project via the below steps, but they don't seem to be adding to the selected Project sub-directory.
Are there any VS config options I need to toggle to allow schemas to be added to sub-directories?

1. I right-click on the Project Sub-Directory that I want to add my schema to, and select 'Add Generated Items...'
2. I select the Consume Adapter Service, and populate all the relevant info in the wizard (SQL Connection, Strongly-Typed Procedure, select stored Procedure and populate a schema prefix)
3. The schemas are then successfully generated, but they add to the Project root (and not the sub-folder). I then have to move the schemas into the sub-directory, then go into each schema and edit the namespace to reflect the title of the sub-folder they should have been created in

When I perform the exact same process as listed above with Map or Orchestrations, the artefacts are added correctly to the relevant Sub-Directory.
When I perform the exact same process, but choose 'Generate Schemas' and select Well-Formed XML, this correctly adds the schema to the relevant Sub-Directory.

I would expect Schemas to do the same thing.

Appreciate any advice on this matter.

Comment: It is Visual Studio 2010 with BizTalk 2010.  Visual Studio 2013 is to be used with BizTalk Server 2013 R2

Comment: Thanks @Dijkgraaf - I suspect that might be it. I believe we're going to be upgrading in the future, so I'll factor this in to a VS upgrade to coincide with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same behavior is observed with BizTalk 2016 / Visual Studio 2015. I guess the product team never bothered with this.

However, there is no stopping you from moving the files to the correct sub-folder and modify the file namespaces accordingly, but i agree that it's not what you would expect.

You could post your feedback on the general page for this: https://feedback.azure.com. (yes it's not Azure but this is where they want you to post issues).

Comment: Cheers r3verse, I did a little more digging (Im new to my role/BizTalk) and we're using the correct combo of VS and BizTalk versions, so Im glad to hear someone else has been able to replicate it elsewhere